# How to get values from different table and insert the ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
dbo.confirmend_Orders 
EmpID (FK) | Client (FK) | StartDate | EndDate | **LocationID (FK) | POCID (FK)**
```

In my .aspx page, I have controls for EmpId, clientID to insert those into the above table, but not for LocationID and POCID.

How do I get values of LocationID and POCID, which is from other tables and insert those into the table dbo.ConfirmEnd_Orders?

```
Dbo.Contacts
Address1| Address2 | CityID (FK) | ContactID(PK)

dbo.POC
FName| Lastname | Mob1 | POCID (PK)
```

Comment: girish are you going to insert bulk data or single record i.e. one at  a time?

Comment: I'm inserting from the form.. Its one at a time.. The problem is with the Location and POC IDs.

Comment: Can you show us the `dbo.Contacts` and `dbo.PointOfContact` tables? So we can see the table relationships.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.confirmend_Orders (LocationId,POCID) 
SELECT locationId,POCID FROM dbo.anotherTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.ConfirmEnd_Orders(EmpId,clientID,LocationID,POCID)
    select  vEmpId, vclientID,t2.LocationID,t3.POCID from
    dbo.ConfirmEnd_Orders t1 inner join dbo.Contacts t2
    on t1.LocationID = t2.LocationID inner join dbo.PointOfContact t3 on t1.POCID =t3.POCID
```

Comment: I don't think this works because LocationID is in the table "dbo.Contacts" and POCID from "dbo.PointOfContact"..